# Errors with reading from a json file through python program

Tags: python, json, pycharm

I am getting errors about the plugin of my program, basically what I am task to do is to extract summaries from a json file which is from a cowrie honeypot, and print it all the countries, like how many countries are written in that json file by using plugins like geoip and geolite2.

Here is the program and the error I am getting, I guess the problem is about the pathing of my program from the source of the file. Any help would really be appreciated

The error I am getting:
[image: error]

My code:

```
import glob
import json
import gmplot
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint
from geoip import geolite2

ips = []
for fn in glob.glob("C:/Users/Bennet/Desktop/Random/forin/cowrie/log/cowrie.json.*"):
 with open(fn, "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)
        if data['eventid'] == "cowrie.session.connect":
            ips.append(data['src_ip'])

lats = []
longs = []
for ip in ips:
  data = geolite2.lookup(ip)
  if data is None:
    continue
  lats.append(data.location[0])
  longs.append(data.location[1])

gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(0,0, 2)
gmap.heatmap(lats, longs)
gmap.draw("mymap.html")
pprint(countries)
```

Cowrie.Json file(logs): [Inside of the cowrie logs I need to read from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjaps.png)

content of the cowrie logs:

```
{"eventid": "cowrie.session.connect", "src_ip": "5.8.32.72", "src_port": 3518, "timestamp": "2018-03-05T00:02:43.158673Z", "message": "New connection: 5.8.32.72:3518 (10.240.0.23:2222) [session: e057e76d0f2a]", "dst_ip": "10.240.0.23", "system": "cowrie.ssh.factory.CowrieSSHFactory", "protocol": "ssh", "isError": 0, "session": "e057e76d0f2a", "dst_port": 2222, "sensor": "garethowenson"}
```

Error after getting the ip address
[image: Error after getting the ip address]

Comment: Hi. Please post your code as text, not images. As it's impossible for us to copy paste and try the code out. There's a "code block" in the question editor, use that for your code.

Comment: Will do now, sorry about that It's my first time posting after a long time.

Comment: No worries, but I have a hard time seeing how this has to do with how long or not someone's posted for help. Think "how would I like to test this" when asking for help anywhere in life. "If someone came to me, asking for help, how would I want the person to frame it" :) Anyway, the edit looks better :)

Comment: Done, thanks for the help btw, will remember that now everytime I post stuff.

Comment: Oh, if it's nothing sensetive in `cowrie.json` could you add the relevant parts you're struggling with? Especially the `data['src_ip']` part :)

Comment: Hi thanks for helping, I don't know how to put a file on this platform but I'll put a picture of the cowrie.json just to show you what's inside the file.

Comment: That would be great, just add it in code blocks :) at least the relevant line.

Comment: Thought that there might have been an issue with the input data being empty or something. but doing `print(data['src_ip'])` would prove me wrong.

Comment: Hi, I tried to do that but unfortunately I got an another error stating "AttributeError: 'List' object has no attribute 'print'

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/Torxed/b94ee2151b702caffddbe67056171777

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much, I did tried and it worked but unfortunately I am still getting errors after printing all the IP address on that file. I am going to put a screenshot on it. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: I think the problem is the plugin, do you recommend me reinstalling the plugin (geolite2) or should I reinstall pycharm?

Comment: I'd submit an issue ticket on their github tbh.

Comment: Hi thanks for the recommendation, apparently based from my research geolite2 was already discontinued and I am just going to use https://app.ipapi.co/bulk/ to scan and check all the countries through their ip address. Thank you very much for the help once again.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know the geolite2-module, but if I understand the error message right, the fault is to pass `geolite2.lookup()` a string (`ip`), but it requires a bytes-like object.

Did you tried `geolite2.lookup(bytes(ip, 'utf-8'))` at line 19 already?

Comment: It actually expects [a string](https://pythonhosted.org/python-geoip/#usage) according to the docs. I recon this is just bad input data that can't beconverted to a bytes object at some point and a check has gone bad. (Edit: I was wrong on the assumption, not on the doc link)

Comment: Hi, I tried to do that but now I am getting an error about it that says "TypeError: string argument without an encoding"

Comment: @Themadchemist I'm sorry, I missed the second argument ("encoding") for bytes().
`bytes(ip, 'utf-8')` would be correct.
But after having a look into the docs, I think @Torxed pointed out correctly, that there seems to be sth wrong with your json data. Did you try printing the json-data 'src_ip' out?

Comment: yes I did, thanks to @Torxed code, it works wonderfully but my current dilemma is the geolite plugin, it seems like it does not work with my system as I have some of my colleagues from university try the same code on their system and it works. I am just going to manually geolocate the ip address and use that to my report.